# Xcode Graph Calculator sin(X) cos(x) tan(x)

Tags: xcode, core-graphics, calculator

I want to create a graphic calculator and Im stuck with the graph bit. I want to know how to plot a graph for sin(x) cos(x) tan(x). I have made the grid already. I dont want to use core plot framework.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of help do you seek? I made several class for graphing (data source, controller, views, etc.) but it's 2500 lines and 12 class. Way too much to be posted here. Tell us on which part you need help (drawing axes, computing the scale, etc.) and we may be able to help. I mention axes and scale since these are the key points of the drawing.

Comment: Can you be more specific? You don't even say whether you're working in MacOS X or iOS, let alone what you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Jean Yes I need help with drawing the axes and scaling, thanks for you help!

Comment: @Caleb Sorry I didn't mention what the project was on. It's on iOS. iPad more specifically. The problem Im having is with drawing the axes and scaling.

Comment: Have you looked at [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)?

Comment: @Jean Hello Jean I found this on youtube and that is basically how I would want the graph to work. Please let me know if you can help. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To actually plot the function, do like you would with paper and pencil: evaluate the function for a number of inputs. Then draw lines to connect the resulting points.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo-code that could answer your question:

```
for i = xmin to xmax do
{
   draw XY point at X=(i*x_scale_factor+x_offset) and Y=(sin(i)*y_scale_factor+Y_offset);
}
```

*And beware: don't use floats in for loops*

**EDIT in response to comments**

The easiest way to proceed, IMHO, would be to get the bounds of your view, to get the min and max values of your data on both X and Y axis.

You then can use a `NSAffineTransform` instance to transform the coordinates of your drawings. So everything can be done in your graphic coordinates, which is easier. You can write a label at coordinates (4.6, 3.2*10-7) if you wish to. This is a key point to get you started. The road is long. But using `NSAffineTransform` will make it easier.

Comment: Just to clarify: floats are okay as loop variables, but don't test them for equality; use <, >, <=, etc.

Comment: Which does tend to happen in a for loop… `for (double d = 0; d < 10.0; d+=0.1) ...`

Answer (score 0):

Not that I would actually do this (I would look at Core Plot), but you could plot such a graph using a Core Image generator filter, like this:

```
//wavelength and magnitude are distances in destination pixels. Think of them as the width and height of each wave.
kernel vec4 sineWave(float wavelength, float magnitude, __color color)
{
    vec2 coord = destCoord();
    coord.y -= magnitude;
    coord /= vec2(wavelength, magnitude / 2.0);
    float pi = radians(180.0);

    float value = sin(coord.x * pi);

    //Smaller threshold = finer wave line. For a gradient, replace the comparison with 1.0 - abs(…).
    float threshold = 0.1;
    float alpha = abs(coord.y - value) <= threshold;
    return color * alpha;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Quartz Composer rendering output from this kernel]

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for you help! The idea is to create something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cIh1Ohrfzs   I have the grid and the calculator part working but would like to know how to plot the trigonomic functions into the grid.